# Using fonts in Next js API route

Tags: next.js, vercel, sharp, next.js14

I'm doing some basic image processing in a Next js API route where I am using sharp to turn svg text to a png. The issue is that the custom font is not being loaded, which seems to be resulting in the error (though this may be unrelated),
`Fontconfig error: No writable cache directories`. The app is deployed on Vercel.

I am wondering how to load fonts in the public directory in a Next js API route.

I tried using next's `localFont` function to load custom fonts but this seems to only work with react components not API routes.

Comment: What public directory?

Comment: @TimRoberts [ref](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/static-assets)

Comment: @TimRoberts I think he wants to load a font file contained in his projects `public` directory into his API route. For some reason.

Comment: Clearly, more details are needed.  Are you trying to allow the user to UPLOAD fonts in a place where they can be seen?  Are you trying to pre-populate a directory with a bunch of fonts?

Comment: @FabioNettis what would you recommend?

Comment: @ReubenDrummond what exactly are you trying to accomplish that you need a font file inside your route? Are you trying to use `ImageResponse`?

Answer (score 2):

I think we probably have the same goal - to convert an SVG to PNG for better cross browser / device support.

I was able to solve this, but can't say I know exactly how. But here are some things that were helpful to me.

First, an ENV var that points at a `fonts.conf` file should be added. You want this to be the path where your API page route runs, which is a Lambda function. I thought it would be `/var/task` like some suggestions on Github.

But I ended up console logging the cwd and discovered that my monorepo setup was causing them to run at `/var/task/packages/app`. I'd recommend importing `path` and logging `path.cwd()` in your handler to find the right path for you.

That config file will tell Fontconfig where to find a writable cache directory. The default value is not writable on the Lambda function, so you want to use the tmp directory that is available.

My env var:

```
FONTCONFIG_PATH=/var/task/packages/app/fonts
```

Here's my `fonts.conf`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/var/task/packages/app/fonts/</dir>
  <cachedir>/tmp/fonts-cache/</cachedir>
  <config></config>
</fontconfig>
```

I placed this file in a `fonts` dir at the root of my NextJS app, and I also placed all of my custom font `.ttf` files in that directory.

Where things get a little surprising is that you need to read the font files into the serverless function - https://vercel.com/guides/how-can-i-use-files-in-serverless-functions

So here's how I get the API page route to pull in my fonts and the `fonts.conf` at the start of my handler:

```js
  const fontsDir = path.join(process.cwd(), "fonts");
  console.log(`Checking fonts in: ${fontsDir}`);
  fs.readdir(fontsDir, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Error reading fonts directory:", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Available fonts:", files);
    }
  });
```

You may also want to ensure the cache directory is available. Oddly without this, subsequent runs of the serverless function would use the same font from the previous invocation. I use a different font across different images, if you're only using one font this might not be necessary.

```js
  fs.mkdirSync(path.resolve(process.cwd(), "tmp", "fonts-cache"), {
    recursive: true,
  });
```

With all of that in place, Sharp is slowly but reliably converting my SVGs to PNG with custom fonts, making my images appear much better on iPhone than they were as SVGs. The only issue I've found is that sharp is applying a bit different kerning on some fonts than desktop browsers, but its barely perceptible.